# How can I only print the the current logged in user data in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

## models.py

```
class placement(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='placeid', null=True, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)  
    ad_space=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)  
    PID_TYPE = (  
        ('FN','FORMAT_NATIVE'),  
        ('FNB','FORMAT_NATIVE_BANNER'),  
        ('FI','FORMAT_INTERSTITIAL'),  
        ('FB','FORMAT_BANNER'),  
        ('FMR','FORMAT_MEDIUM,RECT'),  
        ('FRV','FORMAT_REWARDED_VIDEO'),  
    )

    format = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices = PID_TYPE,default = 'FN',blank=False, null=False)
    pid=models.CharField( max_length=50,default='',blank=False, null=False)
    cpm=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False, null=False)
    ADS_TYPE=(
        ('FB','FACEBOOK'),
        ('G','GOOGLE'),
    )
source=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=ADS_TYPE,default='FB',blank=False, null=False)
    comments=models.TextField(default='',blank=False, null=False)  
    objects=models.Manager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("dashapp:disp")
```

## views.py

```
class createPlace(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):  
    fields=('name','ad_space','format','pid','cpm','source','comments')
    model=placement  
    template_name='createpl.html'  
    def form_valid(self, form):  
        form.instance.user = User.objects.get(id = self.request.user.id)  
        return super(createPlace, self).form_valid(form)  


class Idlist(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    model=placement
    template_name='placement_list.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set=super().get_queryset()
        return query_set.filter(placement.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))
```

Now What query i have to make in `Idlist` class in `Views.py` to fetch only the current logged in user related data. And the query that I'm Perfroming in `Idlist`  is giving me error as

`Exception Type:    ValueError
Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I'm New to to this and any help would be best for me. Please have a look and help a newbie out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter the queryset itself, like:

```
class Idlist(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    model=placement
    template_name='placement_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set=super().get_queryset()
        return query_set.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

So we apply a `.filter(..)` on the `query_set` such that we only obtain `placement`s with `user` is `self.request.user`.

Comment: It worked!!. I was stuck at this from last night. Thanks a lot Sir!!